# How to play song from Spotify using Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, youtube, spotify

All questions about this topic are outdated and left unanswered. There is no answer and I am trying to create a music app that uses Spotify to search songs and then play the first related song. How do I can achieve this? Is there any module about that topic?

I found a script that uses `Selenium` to achieve the solution but it doesn't help me so much.

If this is not achievable, is there such a method for YouTube? Like search the song name and get the first related song (or video).

I hope you can give me an answer. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

try using
https://pypi.org/project/pyspotify/
refer the documentation for more information
https://pyspotify.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
Hope this helps u
Thank you

Comment: I looked for a while to read the docs. But I still don't find a solution.

Comment: ur requirement is to play the music right?
https://pyspotify.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/#playing-music

Comment: The pip install pyspotify not working for Windows. Because it gives PEP 517 error. Do you have any idea for play music from YouTube?

Answer (score 0):

### have you had i look at spotipy to access Spotify Web Api##

Spotify's Web API only supports 30 second clips,You can do playback of the full track using the mobile SDKs

https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.13.0/

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is such a method for YouTube. There is a module named "pywhatkit".
It is actually a WhatsApp server but you can use it to play music on YouTube. First install it using `pip install pywhatkit` then :

```
import pywhatkit
songOrArtist = input()
pywhatkit.playonyt(songOrArtist)
```

This will open the desired song, you can also give name of any artist and it can play the song.